# Maintain relationships (references) between objects created in the editor and stored in a Scriptable Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop, mesh

so I recently discovered the use Context menu in Unity.  I have a mesh with a bunch of triangles that have 3 vertices each.

I have a scriptable object, `LevelData`

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "LevelData", menuName = "Tactics/LevelData", order = 0)]
public class LevelData : ScriptableObject {
    public List<Tri> AllTris = new List<Tri>();
    public List<Vertex> AllVerts = new List<Vertex>();
   
    public Vertex GetVertexFromVector3(Vector3 position)
    {
        foreach (Vertex v in AllVerts)
        {
            if (v.pos == position)
            {
                return v;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and I set AllTris and AllVerts:

```
 [ContextMenu("Find All Vertices")]
    void GetAllVerts(){
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        levelData.AllVerts = new List<Vertex>();
        for (int t = 0; t < mesh.vertices.Length; t++)
        {
            levelData.AllVerts.Add(new Vertex(t, mesh.vertices[t]));
        }
    }

    [ContextMenu("Find All Triangles")]
    void GetAllTris(){
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        levelData.AllTris = new List<Tri>();
        List<Vertex> verts = levelData.AllVerts;
        for (int t = 0; t < mesh.triangles.Length; t+=3)
        {
            Vertex v1 = verts[mesh.triangles[t+0]];
            Vertex v2 = verts[mesh.triangles[t+1]];
            Vertex v3 = verts[mesh.triangles[t+2]];
            levelData.AllTris.Add(new Tri( (t+3)/3 - 1, v1, v2, v3 ));
        }
    }
```

What I was hoping was when I moved a vertex in AllVerts, that would affect that vertex in AllTris

I created this to test it:

```
    [ContextMenu("Test relationship between AllVerts and AllTris")]
    void MoveVertexAndLogTriangle(){
        Debug.Log(levelData.AllTris.First().First.pos);
        Vertex v1 = levelData.GetVertexFromVector3(levelData.AllTris.First().First.pos);
        v1.pos += Vector3.up;
        Debug.Log(levelData.AllTris.First().First.pos);
    }
```

And this works in before I press play.  It logs the vertex moving one down.

However on runtime, it doesn't work.  My guess is that the link between the vertex in AllVerts and AllTris is lost. but I really dont know.

I put both of the GetAllTris and GetAllVerts in the start method, and it works as intended like this:

```
    private void Start() {


        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        levelData.AllVerts = new List<Vertex>();
        for (int t = 0; t < mesh.vertices.Length; t++)
        {
            //do we need an id?
            levelData.AllVerts.Add(new Vertex(t, mesh.vertices[t]));
        }
        levelData.AllTris = new List<Tri>();
        for (int t = 0; t < mesh.triangles.Length; t+=3)
        {
            Vertex v1 = levelData.AllVerts[mesh.triangles[t+0]];
            Vertex v2 = levelData.AllVerts[mesh.triangles[t+1]];
            Vertex v3 = levelData.AllVerts[mesh.triangles[t+2]];
            levelData.AllTris.Add(new Tri( (t+3)/3 - 1, v1, v2, v3 ));
        }
       
        MoveVertexAndLogTriangle();

    }
```

But I'd like to be able to precalculated all of that to save performance.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work by loading the lists of tris and verts from a scriptable object?  And is there a way around that?  Thanks in advance!

Im wondering if something with Ids could work?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For a direct answer - It's hard to know if I'm in the right ballpark since I can't know what a `Tri` or a `Vertex` is but try using `[SerializeReference]` instead of `[Serializable]` in one or both of those classes.  The more helpful answer might be "just serialize `mesh.triangles` and `mesh.vertices` and implement your helper code as methods (perhaps static methods) that use those as inputs plus whatever other inputs are necessary to do the indexing and operations you need."

Comment: Sorry just a correction - for the direct answer `[SerializeReference]` would be on the `Vertex` field inside of `Tri`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your implementation of `Vertex` or `Tri`.

But in general: When you (de)serialize something in Unity that is not of type `UnityEngine.Object` but just a "normal" `[Serializable]` it is always serialized **BY VALUE**.

Have in mind that a `ScriptableObject` (as most other assets like scenes and prefabs) basically underlying just are a YAML file containing text.

Now when your `ScriptableObject` is loaded from that YAML file, there is no way for the parser to tell that originally an entry within `AllTris` was the same `c#` instance of an element in `AllVerts`.

It will just deserialize both individually as two individual instances without any connection.

Just as an example (note I'm not a YAML expert so my format might be wrong here), let's say you have your classes like

```
public class SomeScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Vertex> AllVerts = new (); 
    public List<Tri> AllTris = new ();

    [Serializable]
    public class Vertex
    {
        public int id;
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
        
        public Vertex(int i, Vector3 vert)
        {
            id = i;
            x = vert.x;
            y = vert.y
            z = vert.z;
        }
    }
    
    [Serializable]
    public class Tri
    {
        public int id;
        public Vertex v1;
        public Vertex v2;
        public Vertex v3;
    
        public Tri(int i, Vertex v1, Vertex v2, Vertex v3)
        {
            id = i;
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
            this.v3 = v3;  
        }
    }
}
```

In YAML it will look somewhat like

```
AllVerts:
- {id: 0, x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}
- {id: 1, x: 2, y: 3, z: 4}
- {id: 2, x: 3, y: 4, z: 5}
- ...

AllTris:
- id: 0
  v1: {id: 0, x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}
  v2: {id: 1, x: 2, y: 3, z: 4}
  v3: {id: 2, x: 3, y: 4, z: 5}
- ...
```

Now how should the serializer while parsing this know that the vertices are supposed to be linked to items within triangles?

It works for `UnityEngine.Object` references as the Unity serializer specifically handles those via their GUID stored in the `.meta` files (that's why all references are lost if you loose a `.meta` file).

---

Now how to go about it then?

Tbh, it is not really clear to me yet where exactly you want to go with that. But you would have to make sure to use a different way of referencing / identifying the vertices in a unique way.

=> Why not simply stick to the way Unity does it: Instead of storing the actual `Vertex` instances into the `Triangle` they simply store the **index** of vertices in the entire `vertices` array.

You could do the same and in your `Tri` only pass on the three indices to your `Vertex` instances within the `AllVerts`.

This would probably also answer

> //do we need an id?

If you simply go by index - no, not really.

---

Which again yields the question: What speaks against just sticking to Unity's format of [`vertices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html) as `Vector3[]` and [`triangles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-triangles.html) as `int[]` simply referencing the vertices by index?

This format already is serializable, directly obtainable and processable by [`Mesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) and for now I don't see any operation you can do with your format you couldn't with Unity's.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, ah that makes a lot of sense,   In terms of not using the default mesh.vertices and using the indexes, I think it was because I had all right triangles I was finding the point at the conrner and the points on the either side of the hypotenuse and those didnt align with the order in mesh.vertices.  Its been a couple days since I looked at the code though so idk.  I solved it by adding ints cornerpointIndex, longestEdgePoint1Index, and longestPoint2Index to the Tri class that corresponded to the index in mesh.vertices.  Thank you!